# Is sqlmap traceable?

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, forensics

Is sqlmap still traceable when we use --tor --user-agent and macchanger?

For example:

```
sqlmap -u "[vulnerable_website_link]" --tor --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" with macchanger.
```

Comment: Changing MAC isn't necessary i think?

Answer (score 7):

**No.** The traffic is tunnelled through ToR, so it is just as untraceable as any other use of ToR. In practice you are not traceable at all, unless you make some silly mistake like including your real name in a request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything goes through your ISP he can report attack. But the sysadmins of the site you are attacking and cops will have very hard time tracing you, if you ISP don't report the attack =D.

Comment: It's correct that your traffic will go through your ISP, but they won't be able to track what you're actually sending because you're using tor. So they can't/won't report you. The only thing they're able to recognise is that you're using tor, in some situations this could be enough information to connect you to some activities.

Comment: There's always chance to trace you as I said ISP can report that he detect attack. The most secure way is to spoof your mac address(companies pretend that is unique for all machines) and connect to public wi-fi. Then TOR will only slow you, so its useless.

Comment: They can't report an attack because they don't know what you're doing. They can only report the usage of Tor. And Tor provides much better anonymity than simply going to a public wifi and using linklayer address spoofing - the attacked system can track you down to that place and use then e.g. security camera records to get your identity. With Tor, you don't reveal from where your ip packets come - unless your enemy has the capability to track significant areas of the global internet.

Comment: You're using tor as a proxy, so everything you send to your ISP will be encrypted, and the ISP will have no idea about the content and destination of your packets. There is no way for the ISP to analyze your traffic, so it doesn't matter whether you're using OpenVAS, Nessus or any other vulnerability scanner - they simply can't look into your traffic. Please read about Tor and onion routing if don't believe me. Additionally, ISPs only store your connection metadata, not your actually packets, that wouldn't be possible due to the immense storage space that would occupy.

Comment: And using security cameras to investigate major crime (like computer crime is considered to be) is actually quite realistic (although people in movies do that, too...).

Comment: I agree about the encryption, the the problem is that they are making too much noise, also some of them have information in the header file(not all of them and not sure about sqlmap), also there are tons of possibilities there might be bug and TOR wouldn't encrypt the packets. I hope that this with sec. cameras is joke. Also I didn't say that TOR isn't secure, but probably there's nothing that can secure you. There are bugs in Firefox(the browser TOR mainly uses), and somebody may use those bugs just like anonymous to catch pedos.

Comment: The security cameras are not a joke but an example. If you attack a system, the admins of the attacked system will probably see the source ip address of your attack. They will go to the police and provide them with the found ip address. The police will then track this ip address to the public wifi you're talking about, and will then start investigating there. If they find out that there are pre-installed security cameras (like it's common on public places like e.g. train stations), they will go to the operator of these cameras and ask them for the records. That's common practice.

Comment: In contrary, Tor can't easily be traced to a physical location where police officers could find physical evidence for you having been there. Also Tor encrypts whole packet, including header information. I agree that you can't achieve full security and that bugs in Tor could leak information about you, but assuming that the Tor implementation behaves excatly as specified, it gives a pretty good anonymity that doesn't rely on your physical location.

Comment: user19426, and you will be the only one who is connected to this wi-fi, also when you spoof your MAC address, you can make your laptop MAC to look like phone MAC address or table. So they will have no idea that they are searching somebody with laptop. On second place they will have no evidence to you because probably there will be other people who are connected, and if you didn't attack something really important they will leave the case. Also if they want soon or later they will find you no matter do you use TOR or you are connection from pub networks or both,lulzsec is proof

Comment: Yes, but if you didn't attack something really importang, they also won't take the effort of tracing you through Tor. But I agree that it's very probable that you get caught no matter what "stealth" technologies you use if the ones tracing you are highly interested in doing so.

Comment: -1 because this is misleading. Traffic tunnelled through ToR is effectively untraceable. At least, not unless you're up against a powerful adversary like the NSA.

Comment: What about DNS leaks paj28 ?